# about symbols in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define-struct student (first last major))

(define student1 (make-student "John" "Smith" 'CS))
(define student2 (make-student"Jane" "Jones" 'Math))
(define student3 (make-student "Jim" "Black" 'CS))

#;(define (same-major? s1 s2)
  (symbol=? (student-major s1)
            (student-major s2)))
```

when I type these in, I get the answer I expect.

```
;;(same-major? student1 student2) -> FALSE
;;(same-mejor? student1 student3) -> True
```

But when I want to find out if the students have the same first name, it tells me that they expect a symbol as a 1st argument, but given John.

```
(define (same-first? s1 s2)
  (symbol=? (student-first s1)
            (student-first s2)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'CS` and `'Math` are symbols, "John", "Jane" and "Jim" are not (they're strings). As the error message is telling you, the arguments to `symbol=?` need to be symbols.

To compare strings for equality, you can use `string=?` or just `equal?` (which works with strings, symbols and pretty much everything else).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
(symbol=? (student-major s1)
          (student-major s2)))
```

To this:

```
(string=? (student-major s1)
          (student-major s2)))
```

Notice that you're comparing *strings* not *symbols*, so the appropriate equality procedure must be used.